# Lua How do I add a space between small and capital letters

Tags: lua, space, letter

I have a function to put the first letter of a string into uppercase.

```
function firstToUpper(str)
   return string.gsub(" "..str, "%W%l", string.upper):sub(2)
end
```

Now I need a function to add a space between small and big letters in a string like:

HelloWorld ----> Hello World

Do you know any solution for Lua?

Comment: `s=s:gsub("%f[%u]%f[%L]", " ")`

Answer (score 4):

`str:gsub("(%l)(%u)", "%1 %2")` returns a string that comes with a space between any lower upper letter pair in `str`.

Please read https://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#pdf-string.gsub

Answer (score 0):

```
local function spaceOut(str)
     local new = str
     repeat
         local start,finish = new:find("%l%u")
         new = new:gsub("%l%u",new:sub(start,start).." "..new:sub(finish,finish),1)
     until new:find("%l%u") == nil
     return new
 end

 print(spaceOut("ThisIsMyMethodForSpacingWordsOut"))
```

Comment: all you do here is already supported by string.gsub. there is no need to use string.find and a loop. `new` is also superfluous. why not name your parameter `new` or use `str`?

Comment: Before I wrote this script, I thought you couldn't change the value of a parameter in a function. Thanks for letting me know about this easier method